# How to get the current Firebase uid from android service?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i want to push the current user location to the  Firebase using uid as key 
how i can get the current user from background service

```
public class TrackService extends Service ....{
...........
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO: insert the new location to the Firebase location childe
    Log.i(TAG, location.toString());

    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location.toString());


        DatabaseReference key= root.child("Location").child(?USERID?).push();
                key.setValue(location);

}....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The currently logged in user is always available with [FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) at any time in any component of your app.  Note that this can return null if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Thank you so much ,i didn't know that i can get the user anywhere

Comment: Consider accepting this answer so the other users know it has been solved